# How to enter multiple variable values at once?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation like this:

```
Declare @studentId INT = 12;
INSERT INTO someTable (col1, col2)
SELECT @studentId, someValueForCol2 from anotherTable where isActive = 1
```

the studentId variable takes 10 different values. One way is to manually change the variable's value and execute the query 10 times, however it feels like this is not the right way to do this. Is there a way to give all those 10 values to the query on the same time?
To make it clear:
If the select statement returns 20 records than it would have to be 200 inserts in database, 20 records for each studentId.
Thank you

Comment: are you ruling out iteration?  is this just in sql?  you can interate to do that, using any scripting type language.

Comment: @blamb no need to resort to looping for something like this.

Comment: i gather your right, as a full stack engineer those are my solutions, i dont like overcomplicated sql, your answer is more elegant, not sure if it will work, but it is concise, ill give you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a table valued constructor for this. Let's say you had two studentID values of 1 and 2. Here is how you could do this.

```
SELECT Students.StudentID
    , someValueForCol2 
from anotherTable 
cross join (values(1),(2))Students(StudentID)
where isActive = 1
```

Comment: Yes, it works fine and I see what are you doing. I like this solution.

Comment: If this works you should consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: I try to mark it earlier but was not allowing me to do so saying it was too early to accept an answer lol